# Headless Chrome page source different from browser

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to mine a website using selenium in python with the chromedriver. The element I am looking for is rendered and I can interact with it when I use the chrome driver without the headless option. When I use the headless option, the element is no longer present.Can someone point me in the right direction to fix this issue? Here's the code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

chrome_options=Options()
chrome_options.add_argument('--mute-audio')
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')

driver=webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=chromedriver_path,options=chrome_options)

driver.get("https://www.youtube.com/user/PaymoneyWubby/about")
el = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"/html/body/ytd-app/div/ytd-page-manager/ytd-browse/div[3]/ytd-c4-tabbed-header-renderer/app-header-layout/div/app-header/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/yt-formatted-string"))
)
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't have an answer to your question (I suspect that Youtube knows the browser is in headless mode and is not fond of web-scrapers, especially ones using their own company's browser -- see if you get a different result using Firefox) but I do have a suggestion to help you to cleanup your xpath:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

chrome_options=Options()
chrome_options.add_argument('--mute-audio')
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')

driver=webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=chromedriver_path,options=chrome_options)

driver.get("https://www.youtube.com/user/PaymoneyWubby/about")
el = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"//yt-formatted-string[@id='subscriber-count']"))
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed this issue with setting user-agent option.

```
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
chrome_options.add_argument("--user-agent=Mozilla...")
```